# Aloe Vera exposed to frost - cut the leaves or let it heal?

Tags: aloe, frost

An obvious mistake from my side.

I left the plant outside while it was freezing.

Now back indoors.

Any advice what to do with leaves now?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you cut the leaves at the margin between green living tissue and dead brown tissue you will get some plant fluids coming out.

Aesthetics says trim and clean up or you can do nothing for a few weeks.  The dead tissue will dry up and then you can trim.

Either way it will be a long time until this plant looks nice again.  If you don't want to wait you could get another one or propagate this one to start over.